# Toad SQL optimizer not returning elapsed time

Tags: oracle, toad, sql-optimization

I've got a SQL script I'm trying to run through the Auto Optimize SQL tool in Toad. I've created alternatives (313 of them), and have started testing them, but when I run more than one alternative at a time, I don't get an Elapsed Time value back for each tested alternative.

"Hide Slower Alternatives" is not checked; and I've checked in, and seen it run several of the selected alternatives that have a blank Elapsed Time.

My thought is that Toad is suppressing the value for some reason, but I can't find any documentation on why it would do so (and more importantly on how to turn off if it's doing so).

Any help in why the data is not presented, and how to get Toad to ***always*** fill in the Elapsed Time would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Toad are you using? Using Toad 12.7 and Toad 12.8 beta the "Elapsed Time" column is filled in following a retest of selected alternatives. Are your execution times showing as 0.00? Does the query execute so quickly that the elapsed time accuracy is insufficient to show anything? My first test query that was the case. Running a slower query and I'm seeing data there.

Comment: Toad 12.6; the value for Elapsed time is empty (no "not executed", "0.00", nor "> faster alternative"). The runs are all taking >5 minutes, so it's not that the execution is too fast to measure.

Comment: I tried in 12.6 and cannot reproduce. I was thinking that it might be a bug that was later resolved, but that doesn't appear to be the case. If you click in the elapsed time column and re-size it do you see text? I saw an initial text update issue where the text didn't change from pending until I clicked in there. If that's not it I'm not sure what to suggest other than try your examples in the full-blown Quest SQL Optimizer application to accomplish your goals.